# How to make a JQuery CSS menu item clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have a css menu that I'm trying to use. When you click a main menu item that has a sub item the menu will expand to show the sub items. The menu works great except for one thing. When you click the main menu items that have sub items it will not open the requested link. It will only expand the menu. How can I edit the jquery so if the main menu item has a href that the menu will expand and open the link for the main menu item?

Here's the code.

Here's the code I'm using...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
  $('.menu > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");
    
  $('.menu > ul > li > a').each(
    function(){
        $(this.firstChild).wrap('<span></span>');
    });
       
  $('.menu > ul > li > a').click(function(){
 var checkElement = $(this).next();
    
    $('.menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
        
    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
      $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
      checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }
    
    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
      $('.menu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
      checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }
    
    if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
 
      return false;
    } else {
      return true; 
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1.05em;
  position: relative;
}
.menu {
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.menu a {
  line-height: 1.3;
}
.menu > ul > li:first-child {
  background: #66665e;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#66665e 0%, #45463d 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #66665e), color-stop(100%, #45463d));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#66665e 0%, #45463d 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#66665e 0%, #45463d 100%);
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.menu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  padding: 12px 10px;
  background: url(menu_images/pattern.png) top left repeat;
  border-top: 1px solid #818176;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #000000;
}
.menu > ul > li:first-child > a > span {
  padding: 0;
}
.menu > ul > li:first-child:hover {
  background: #379bb9;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#379bb9 0%, #2C7C94 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #379bb9), color-stop(100%, #2C7C94));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#379bb9 0%, #2C7C94 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#379bb9 0%, #2C7C94 100%);
}

.menu > ul > li {
  background: #66665e;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#66665e 0%, #45463d 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #66665e), color-stop(100%, #45463d));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#66665e 0%, #45463d 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#66665e 0%, #45463d 100%);
}
.menu > ul > li:hover {
  background: #379bb9;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#379bb9 0%, #2C7C94 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #379bb9), color-stop(100%, #2C7C94));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#379bb9 0%, #2C7C94 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#379bb9 0%, #2C7C94 100%);
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: .9em;
  display: block;
  background: url(menu_images/pattern.png) top left repeat;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #000000;
}
.menu > ul > li > a > span {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.menu > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu > ul > li.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.menu > ul > li.has-sub > a span {
  background: url(menu_images/icon_plus.png) 96% center no-repeat;
}
.menu > ul > li.has-sub.active > a span {
  background: url(menu_images/icon_minus.png) 96% center no-repeat;
}

.menu ul ul {
  display:none; 
  background: #fff;
/*  border-right: 1px solid #a2a194;
  border-left: 1px solid #a2a194; */
}
.menu ul ul li {
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-top: none;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f7f7f7 0%, #ececec 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f7f7f7), color-stop(100%, #ececec));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f7f7f7 0%, #ececec 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#f7f7f7 0%, #ececec 100%);
}
.menu ul ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.menu ul ul a {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
  display: block;
  color: #676767;
  font-size: .8em;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.menu ul ul a:before {
  content: '\00BB'; 
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  color: #379bb9;
}
.menu ul ul a:hover {
  color: #379bb9;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.user_menu_link_selected{

}
.admin_menu_link_selected{
 
}

#submenu_1{

}
#submenu_0 li{

}
#submenu_1 li{

}
#submenu_1 li a{

}
#submenu_1 li:hover a{

}
#submenu_0 li:hover ul li{

}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a class="user_menu_link_selected" href="?m=dashboard&amp;p=dashboard"><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
  <li class="has-sub"><a class="user_menu_link" href="?m=gamemanager&amp;p=game_monitor"><span>Game Monitor</span></a>
   <ul id="submenu_0">
    <li><a href="?m=gamemanager&amp;p=game_monitor&amp;home_cfg_id=25">My Game</a>
     <ul id="submenu_1">
      <li><a title="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx" class="user_menu_link" href="?m=gamemanager&amp;p=game_monitor&amp;home_id-mod_id-ip-port=4-4-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-xxxxx">My Game Server</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="?m=gamemanager&amp;p=game_monitor&amp;home_cfg_id=128">My Game 2</a>
     <ul id="submenu_1">
      <li><a title="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx" class="user_menu_link" href="?m=gamemanager&amp;p=game_monitor&amp;home_id-mod_id-ip-port=3-3-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-xxxxx">My Game Server 2</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class="user_menu_link" href="?m=TS3Admin"><span>TS3 Admin</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="user_menu_link" href="?m=ftp"><span>FTP</span></a></li>
  <li class="has-sub"><a href="?m=administration&amp;p=main" class="admin_menu_link" target="_self"><span>Administration</span></a>
   <ul>
    <li><a class="admin_menu_link" href="?m=addonsmanager&amp;p=addons_manager">Addons Manager</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_menu_link" href="?m=extras">Extras</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_menu_link" href="?m=ftp&amp;p=pure-ftpd_admin">FTP users</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_menu_link" href="?m=user_games">Game Servers</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_menu_link" href="?m=config_games">Game/Mod Config</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_menu_link" href="?m=user_admin&amp;p=show_groups">Groups</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_menu_link" href="?m=modulemanager">Modules</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_menu_link" href="?m=settings">Panel Settings</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_menu_link" href="?m=server">Servers</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_menu_link" href="?m=settings&amp;p=themes">Theme Settings</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_menu_link" href="?m=update">Update Panel</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_menu_link" href="?m=user_admin">Users</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_menu_link" href="?m=litefm&amp;p=litefm_settings">LiteFM Settings</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_menu_link" href="?m=mysql&amp;p=mysql_admin">MySQL Admin</a></li>
    <li><a class="admin_menu_link" href="?m=administration&amp;p=watch_logger">Watch Logger</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-sub"><a href="?m=user_admin&amp;p=edit_user&amp;user_id=1" class="user_menu_link" target="_self"><span>admin</span></a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="?logout">[Logout]</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you do know that this will cause a new page load, which makes your menu to be rendered new again, and therefore the user will never be able to click your submenu-items!?!?

Comment: Good point... I will have to see what else I can do with this.

Comment: if I change the event to .hover how can I keep the sub items open on hover? $('.menu > ul > li > a').hover(function(){

Comment: do this with css, and not jquery